# How to reuse CURL and set different doh url at every time in libcurl?

Tags: c++, network-programming, libcurl

I set the hosts file on PC like this:

```
127.0.0.1 www.baidu.com
```

Then I wrote a simple test:

```cpp
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "www.baidu.com");
        if (i == 1)
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DOH_URL, "https://dns.alidns.com/dns-query");
        else
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DOH_URL, NULL);
            
        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "==================================================" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Time: " << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "res = " << res << std::endl;
        char *url = NULL;
        curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, &url);
        if (url)
            printf("Redirect to: %s\n", url);
        std::cout << "==================================================" << std::endl;
        curl_easy_reset(curl);
    }
}
```

And the result is like:

```
==================================================
Time: 0
res = 7
Redirect to: http://www.baidu.com/
==================================================
==================================================
Time: 1
res = 0
Redirect to: http://www.baidu.com/
==================================================
==================================================
Time: 2
res = 0
Redirect to: http://www.baidu.com/
==================================================
```

As defined in CURLcode, `r = 0` means `CURLE_OK`, and `r = 7` means `CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT`.

I don't understand the result. When `i == 0`, I set `DOH_URL` to `NULL`, so it is normal that it couldn't connect. But when `i == 2`, I also set `DOH_URL` to `NULL`, and I do reset operation, and set `DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT` to 0, why it still could connect?

Comment: @273K So the `curl_easy_reset` operation did not shutdown the existing connection? Is there any idea that I could shutdown the existing connection, and set CURL with different option without delete and construct a new CURL?

Comment: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1L);
 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curl easy uses the existing connection of the 2nd iteration on the 3rd iteration. See [Name Resolving](https://everything.curl.dev/libcurl/names)

> libcurl **tries hard to re-use an existing connection** rather than to create a new one. The function that checks for an existing connection to use **is based purely on the name and is performed before any name resolving is attempted**.

See [curl_easy_reset()](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_reset.html)

> **It does not change** the following information kept in the handle: **live connections**, the Session ID cache, the DNS cache, the cookies, the shares or the alt-svc cache.